# How to make this code work with the rest?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am trying to build a scroll indicator using 3 div elements. All code (meaning the 3 div HTML,CSS,JS) seems to work by itself in codepen.io but when i am using Atom with the rest or my project it seems to stop working.

I tried putting the 3 div's first before everything else. All the way to the end. Using other divs as parents but nothing seems to work.

```js
  window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

  function myFunction() {
    var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || 
document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - 
document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";
  }
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
 /* Global Stylings */



/* ID and Class Stylings */

#containter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#Landing{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#projects {
  background-color: ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#gallery {
  background-color: ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#logo{
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
}

.scroll {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.scrollindicator {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
.progress-bar {
  height: 0%;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 8px;
```

```html
<div id="containter" class="snap">
      <div class="progress-container">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div id="Landing" class="scroll">
        <img id="logo" src="AC-Logo.png" alt="Logo">
     </div>
      <div id="projects" class="scroll">
      </div>
      <div id="gallery" class="scroll">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scroll.js">
    </script>
  </body>
```

The div ID= myBar should show a progress of scrolling throughout the whole page and should be visible at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: fixed` to your class progress-container .

Edit : `scroll-snap-type` wasn't working because your elements weren't included in the container having the property `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` . So I added everything in 'containter', making that css property work again.

Had to change a bit your Javascript so the custom scrollbar should work again.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('containter');
    var winScroll = elem.scrollTop;
    var height = elem.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
 /* Global Stylings */



/* ID and Class Stylings */

#containter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#Landing{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#projects {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#gallery {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#logo{
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
}

.scroll {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.scrollindicator {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;  
  position: fixed;
}

/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
.progress-bar {
  height: 0%;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div onscroll="myFunction()" id="containter" class="snap">
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Landing" class="scroll">
      <img id="logo" src="AC-Logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div id="projects" class="scroll"></div>
    <div id="gallery" class="scroll"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="scroll.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Updated my answer, everything should work as you wanted now. Feel free to ask any question if you need more precision.

Comment: Thank you so much Mambo! what exactly was wrong? i didnt understand

Comment: Update: I see what you did with the HTML, let me see if it works as i envisioned. but it seems like it should. 'containter' whats supposed to be like a page wrap but thats fine if it still works in the end haha

Comment: *Update: Everything works great! thanks so much Mambo!

Comment: No problem mate ! You cann still add a container to wrap all your page, it won't change much :)

Answer (score 1):

Your css styling was wrong. Check out the snippet!

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

  function myFunction() {
    var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || 
document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - 
document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";
  }
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
 /* Global Stylings */



/* ID and Class Stylings */

#containter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  position: fixed; // Make the bar stick to the left of the screen
}

#Landing{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#projects {
  background-color: ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#gallery {
  background-color: ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#logo{
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
}

.scroll {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.scrollindicator {
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
.progress-bar {
  height: 0%;
  background: #ccc; // Set color to the actual bar that changes height
  width: 8px;
```

```html
    <div id="containter" class="snap">
      <div class="progress-container">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Landing" class="scroll">
      <img id="logo" src="AC-Logo.png" alt="Logo">
   </div>
    <div id="projects" class="scroll">
    </div>
    <div id="gallery" class="scroll">
    </div>
    <script src="scroll.js">
    </script>
```

Comment: yeah, but the rest isnt working. "scroll-snap-style" specifically

Comment: What is scroll-snap-style if I may ask? @ZealousSloth

Comment: its a function to make "sections" of your page 'snap' into place when a certain point of scrolling is reached